# Auto notification system

Tags: php

i am a beginner in php coding. i am developing a blood bank management system. Now i want to set a reminder system for each registered user in the blood management system. this reminder will be displayed in the users in every three months when they can donate blood. i don't want to use cronjob. i just simply want to display the reminder message in the users page. Now by this following code the date is not working and all users reminder is showing in one user page.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you insert your code in a code block rather than posting a picture of it?

Comment: actually i dont know about code block. i am new bee in coding.need help badly

Comment: What @tshimkus meant was: please add your code to your question *as code* instead of an image. Images tend to disappear over time. Also, if we need to try something we want to be able to copy/paste your code into our own editors.

Comment: You can use something like `WHERE DATEDIFF(NOW(), donation_date) > 90`. The `DATEDIFF()` function will return an integer of the number of days between `NOW` and the `donation_date` column, and if it is greater than 90 days that row will be returned. That's with the assumption that `donation_date` is the last time the person donated

Comment: If `donation_date` is the date where a user can donate again you can use `WHERE donation_date <= NOW()`

Comment: many many thanks DATEDIFF() is working. But after 90 days when the system will show the reminder then i have to update the date. Is there any way to show the reminder in every three months automatically. i meant where i dont need to set up the date again. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is in the `WHERE`

Try `WHERE donation_date <= NOW()`